# How to properly push back and then loop through vector of objects located in the heap?

Tags: c++, object, vector, heap-memory

I have the following class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
class minimal
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    minimal(int x = NAN, int y = NAN)  // default constructor
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    ~minimal(){}
    void setvals(int xin, int yin)
    {
        this->x = xin;
        this->y = yin;
    }
    int getx() {return this->x;}
};
int main() {
    // goal: create a vector of type minimal to be located in the heap
    std::vector<minimal*> vectinheap;

    minimal * min_ptr = new minimal;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        min_ptr->setvals(i, -i);
        vectinheap.push_back(min_ptr);  // send a local copy to vectinheap?
    }
    delete min_ptr;  // free the heap
    min_ptr = nullptr;  // free dangling pointer
    // now how to iterate through vect in heap.. ?
    return 0;
}
```

A couple questions arise from this:

1. When I say `vectinheap.push_back(min_ptr)` is that going to make each value in the vector be pointing to the same instance in the end, or will it append the current instance like I am wanting?
2. After loading the vector located in the heap, how can I then iterate through and access each instance by indexing the vector?

Comment: Could you reduce the shown code to a [mre]? I have the impression that all of the class details are unneeded. Can you ask the question by using simple integers instead? E.g. inside `main()` replace all `minimal` by integer and `min_ptr->setvals(xlocal, ylocal);` by `*min_ptr = i;`. I think you will then realise the answer to your question.

Comment: Do you know the difference of making multiple pointers pointing to the same object and creating new objects?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know how I could make it any more minimal without getting my question completely answered. Its all located in `main.cpp` should I take the break out? My goal is not to have multiple pointers going to same object (see question 1).

Comment: You  only ever delete `min_ptr` and only once, which is correct for the code you show. But if you want to handle multiple objects, don't you wonder why you only delete once?

Comment: Please try as I proposed in my first comment. I believe that **will** get you your question completely answered.

Comment: What is the point of storing `minimal*` instead of `minimal` in the vector in the first place?

Comment: @walnut I have a serious memory problem with the program I am working with. My end goal here is when I loop through this vector, I am accessing members located in the heap.

Comment: Your example shows you know nothing about how C++ memory works, so of course you have a memory problem.
`vector.push_back(min_ptr)` just assigns a copy of the same ptr to every element, then you delete it. It means the entire vector is containing junk data. You should rather store `vector<minimal>`, not `vector<minimal*>`.

Comment: @GeneralCode Vector also allocates its elements on the heap. The `minimal` objects in both `std::vector<minimal>` and `std::vector<minimal*>` are going to be allocated on the heap. In fact the former will likely require less memory because the vector requires only one allocation, while the pointers need individual allocations, each with some overhead.

Comment: If you're new to C++, you should always use `vector<type>` not `vector<type*>`. Later on, if you're storing large types, it may be worthwhile in some cases (Qt does this extensively) to use a `vector<type*>` just so re-ordering elements is efficient. But you have no need to do that here.

Comment: Also, C++ has std::unique_ptr, so you should never use a raw pointer in 99% of cases anymore. `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` covers the example of `vector<T*>` better.

Comment: @walnut okay thank you

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Is a vector containing ~1000 instantiated classes each containing 6 instances considered small in this case? I do not know your definition of large.

Comment: It means the size per element. Generally, vectors are fine with storing elements on the heap unless they need frequent insertions, removals, or swaps inside the container. Anything above 256 bytes or non-trivially copyable data may be considered good to store as a pointer, but it depends on what your actual use-case is. Do `vector<T>` first, unless it becomes prohibitive, then do `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` as a fallback.

Comment: Also, if you think you have a performance issue, always use benchmarks rather than just blindly guess. But chances are, you want `vector<T>`, not `vector<T*>`. Make sense?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Yes, thank you for the insight. Very helpful. This is a great place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've come from a C# or Java background? (hence the reason for trying to new everything?). The way you would do this in C++ would be something along the following lines:

```cpp
int main() {
    // store a vector of minimal structs
    std::vector<minimal> vectinheap;

    int n = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int xlocal = i;  // set dummy vals for filling vectinheap
        int ylocal = -i;

        // emplace_back will construct a new item at the end of the vector
        vectinheap.emplace_back(xlocal, ylocal);
    }


    // and now to iterate (range based for loop - best method)
    for(auto& value : vectinheap)
    {
      std::cout << value.getx() << ' ' <<  value.gety() << std::endl;
    }

    // the less good way using iterators
    for(auto it = vectinheap.begin(); it != vectinheap.end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << it->getx() << ' ' <<  it->gety() << std::endl;
    }

    // and using indices if you really must
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vectinheap.size(); ++i)
    {
      std::cout << vectinheap[i].getx() << ' ' <<  vectinheap[i].gety() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

However, using push_back/emplace_back to construct a simple POD array is a very inefficient approach. It's usually better to allocate once upfront, and simply fill the data. This way you aren't constantly asking the question "can I append one more item to this array without resizing it?" every loop iteration.

```cpp
    int n = 4;

    // allocate enough memory for 'n' structs
    std::vector<minimal> vectinheap(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int xlocal = i;  // set dummy vals for filling vectinheap
        int ylocal = -i;

        // just use the array brackets to access
        vectinheap[i].setvals(xlocal, ylocal);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You'd better rename the `std::vector<minimal*> vectinheap;` to `vect_of_ptr`, because your vector is not in the heap.
2. > When I say vectinheap.push_back(min_ptr) is that going to make each
   >   value in the vector be pointing to the same instance in the end, or
   >   will it append the current instance like I am wanting?

You are pushing the pointer which is pointing to the same `minimal`object allocated on the heap to the vector `vectinheap`.

3. > After loading the vector located in the heap, how can I then iterate
   >   through and access each instance by indexing the vector?

You do:

```
for(const auto& item: vectinheap)
{
    //item is a pointer, you can get your object by dereference it using *
}
```

Notice: You only create one object of `minimal` in the heap, but you push four pointers pointing to it **(the same object)** into your vector. And you have delete the object by `delete min_ptr;`. And looping through the vector and dereference the pointer in it will become **undefined**.

You should fix it by moving `minimal * min_ptr = new minimal;` into your for loop. And **don't forget to delete them** when you are looping through your `vectinheap`.

Comment: Vector data, unless using a custom allocator, is always in the "heap", regardless of whether a pointer or not is used as the `value_type`. Either way, the data will be stored in the "heap".

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Yet the vector itself never is, the way OP declares it. I think that is szppeter's point.

Comment: The vector itself may not be in the heap, but the data in the vector always is. That's worth noting, because I'm 99% sure that's the OP's issue.